# Creating an array of something by not today's date?

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays I'm trying to make. The first one is all the "quotes" with a "follow_up_date" that is today's date. My code looks like:

```
@dailyTasks = Quote.where(:follow_up => 1,:follow_up_date => Date.today())
```

This works perfectly for me and is not the issue.

My next array is the same concept but all the quotes to be added are quotes with a follow_up_date that is not today's date. Something like this is what I'm looking for:

```
@upcomingTasks = Quote.where(:follow_up => 1, :follow_up_date => NOT Date.today())
```

Does anyone know the proper syntax I should be using to add quotes whose date is **NOT** today's date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`where.not`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain/not) to get that negation:

```
@upcomingTasks = Quote.where(follow_up: 1).where.not(follow_up_date: Date.today())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you happen to know of a way to check for future days and days past?

Comment: @LLBrettK No problem!  You could probably do something like `.where('follow_up_date < ?', 60.days.ago)` (or `60.days.from_now
`) -- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-days

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use equality operators

```
today = Date.today
today == some_other_date
```

Can also use `<` and `>` to check if date is earlier or later than another.

```
today < some_other_date
```

If using `Date.today`, it does not compare the exact time like it would if using `Time.now` from other time/date related built-ins.

Comment: I get what your saying, but specifically adding quotes where the follow_up_date is not today's date is still a little tricky for me. If I do something like this `notToDay = Date.today()` and then `:follow_up_date => notToDay`, how do I get it so `notToDay` is everyday but today?

Comment: You literally want it to be equal to every day but today? I don't think the RAM can hold all those days. Would perhaps a simple boolean if it is today or not suffice? If so just check if `Date.today != some_other_date`

Comment: Yeah, but I think the issue is still here `:follow_up_date => NOT Date.today()`. I don't think a boolean can be used in this notation and I wasn't sure what syntax could be used to check for not today.